# How to set a formatter for Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

with this piece of javascript code I can make a post in Spring MVC with no problem.

```
var oc = {
  id: 1,
  date: "2016-04-03",
  type: "1",
};

$.ajax({
    url: "addOC.do",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(oc),
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(object){
       alert();
    }
});
```

Now, the OC Java class has the following structure

```
public class OC{

    private Integer id;
    private Date date;
    private Person person ;
    private String type;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Person{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

When I try to make a post like this

```
var oc = {
  id: 1,
  date: "2016-04-03",
  type: "1",
  person: 1,
};
```

The Person formatter is not being called. I know this because if serialize the oc variable and then post it as following:

```
var form = "id=1&date="2016-04-03"&type="1"&person=1";

$.ajax({
    url: "addOC.do",
    type: "POST",
    data: form,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(object){
       alert();
    }
});
```

The Person formatter is called with no problem.

How can I set a formatter for Jackson JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to post your nested person object like bellow:

```
var oc = {
  id: 1,
  date: "2016-04-03",
  person: {id:2, name:"name"},
  type: "1",
};
```

Comment: Your code works fine but I need to call the Spring MVC Person formatter so I can read the Person object from my DB.

Comment: @MartinMoreno, what do you mean by Person formatter ?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake and added JSON tag to my question. My question is oriented to Spring MVC.